# Call a delete url from routes using ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

How to call an url from routes using ajax ?

The route :

```
Route::delete('dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag}', 'TagCon@destroy')->name('tagdestroy');
```

Controller :

```
public function destroy($id) {
        $tag = Tag::findOrFail($id);
        $tag->delete();

        return response()->json($tag);
    }
```

Ajax code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function () {
        $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
        $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#title_delete').val($(this).data('title'));
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        id = $('#id_delete').val();
    });
    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/' + id,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
                $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).html(index + 1);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

It does nothing maybe because it's not calling the correct route ? However, if I change this `url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/' + id,` to this `url: '{{ URL::route('tagdestroy') }}' + id,` it will return an error `Missing required parameters for [Route: tagdestroy] [URI: dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag}]`

Where is the wrong part with the code ? thanks

**SOLVED**

Got it working now, changed the url call in the ajax function to `url: 'tags/destroy/' + id,` instead of `url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/' + id,` . I have no idea why is it working, the delete method url is still defined as     `Route::delete('dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag}', 'TagCon@destroy')->name('tagdestroy');`, not `Route::delete('tags/destroy/{tag}', 'TagCon@destroy')->name('tagdestroy');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'{{ URL::route('tagdestroy',[Your Params ]) }}
```

You are missing params in your named routes.

Comment: I did include the parameter `url: '{{ URL::route('tagdestroy') }}' + id,`. id is the parameter. Maybe I included the parameter the wrong way ?

Comment: you can make it optional then you can pass it like you have mentioned but you need to update your routes `dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag?}` by this

Comment: I did changed the route as you said to `dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag?}` but still it does nothing. I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

First url work well I think.
Do you check carefully `id` parameter?
I see  in ajax function, you did not declare it.
You call `id` in different function ?

Comment: I did declare it `id = $('#id_delete').val();`

Comment: @SandraVioletta: Can you try `Route::post()` and in ajax` type: "POST"`

Comment: Tried it but still does nothing, no error just not deleting the data

Comment: @SandraVioletta Open web developer of chrome? In tag network, when you click delete. What did you see? (see parameter `dashboard/tags/destroy/`)

Comment: Well, I got this `http://mk1.dev/dashboard/dashboard/tags/destroy/18` with error 404 status code.

Comment: I have no idea where that error 404 came from, confusing

Comment: Got it working now, changed the url call in the ajax function to `url: 'tags/destroy/' + id,` instead of `url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/' + id,` . I have no idea why is it working, when in the route the url is still defined as 'url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag}'. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SandraVioletta My pleasure :D. If you had issues with ajax or javascript, debug on browser is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Is the tag in your uri necessary? I use to omit it on my ajax calls, using it as a POST parameter.
Route:

```
Route::delete('dashboard/tags/destroy', 'TagCon@destroy')->name('tagdestroy');
```

Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function () {
    $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
    $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
    $('#title_delete').val($(this).data('title'));
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    id = $('#id_delete').val();
});
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '{{route('tagdestroy')}}',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(), 'id': id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
            $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
            $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                $(this).html(index + 1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy() {
    $id = e(Input::get('id'));
    $tag = Tag::findOrFail($id);
    $tag->delete();
    return response()->json($tag);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is necessary to determine which data is being deleted by taking the id as the parameter.

Comment: Got it working now, changed the url call in the ajax function to `url: 'tags/destroy/' + id,` instead of `url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/' + id,` . I have no idea why is it working, when in the route the url is still defined as 'url: 'dashboard/tags/destroy/{tag}'. Anyway, thanks a lot!